# Telefon Tel Aviv - SSD Thread Tribute

Tags: music

Personally, the respect I for the group is just not normal.

Talk about such all encompassing, engulfing, trancing, absorptive music.

However, I wanted to start a thread about the techniques and software used, or could have been used at one time, in their music or in this genre of elecro-acoustic in general.

Ableton Live, Beat slicing, classic drum machines, Pro Tools, Analog Synths, glitch repeats/delays, fx, tape manipulation - anything goes.

I want to start this discussion of with one of their interviews from EM magazine.
http://emusician.com/remixmag/artists_interviews/musicians/remix_tapeheads/

This interview covers their production over a few different albums. The techniques they used to create some of their amazing songs, and the lives connected with such compositions.

Some links to their unbelievable music:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vYnmP8HOZ00 - Sound In A Dark Room
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YCspF-lz24A - Fahrenheit Fair Enough
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c3u92RKP2V8 - When It Happens It Moves All By Itself

Ill kick it of with a question related to Telefon: How has this type of music inspired you to push your creative boundaries? How did you respond and what types of explorations in audio resulted from such inspiration?

Answer (score 1):

I've heard of BT spending a very long time on a song editing it and making it "perfect". He did release a plug-in via Izotope but I'm sure that's not all of his tricks up his sleeve.

Thanks for the links - good music.

This genre of music inspired me because two of my favorite artists (BT and Imogen Heap) mix their own tracks. They do it practically all on their own. A few of his songs have made me experiment with delays and stutter-edits (hence my question as to how to make them a few weeks back).

Comment: @Utopia THANK YOU UTOPIA!!!!! I had never listened to BT.... WOW

Comment: @C3Sound No problem. There is a first for everything. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Teflon is amazing, I completely agree. BT and Izotope made a great plu-gin together. It is a fairly expensive version of many plugins that have been free for a long time, but it very well designed for sure.

Answer (score 1):

When the first Zunes were on display at Best Buy, they had the music video for 1.618 (from BT's This Binary Universe) pre-loaded on them.

Those were a pretty intensely inspiring couple of minutes, I could not take off those headphones for anything. I got some weird looks from people in best buy lol

Answer (score 1):

I too am always blown away by Telefon Tel Aviv's work (RIP). I think the strength of their work is based on (relative to lessons sound designers could take away):

- Contrast. Beautiful guitar and vocals next to lush synths next to very skittery percussion. Many artists attempt this blend, but their ability to render each layer as very articulate without creating sonic mush (unless that's the goal, which they do let happen) is pretty well-honed.
- Emotion. Their choices of key, instrumentation and the above contrast creates this amazing sense of melancholy, remembrance, nostalgia, or sometimes just a sunny summer day.
- Disregard for fitting into categories. Song by song it could be shoegazer alt rock or glitchtronica, and it doesn't matter. It all has the same thematic and emotional core, and that's what unites the work(s) all together.

Quite possibly the ultimate "beautifully-shot indie road movie about getting divorced and driving across the US in the autumn" music. :-p

Comment: I tend towards clicktronicglitchsnaptortioncore myself. :-)